# Finding graph corresponding to $\int_0^{\sqrt{x} } e^{ -\frac{u^2}{x} } du$

Tags: calculus, integration

> [Question 36](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf): Finding graph corresponding to $\int_0^{\sqrt{x} } e^{ -\frac{u^2}{x} } du$
> [image]
> $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$

Clearly we can't say the function is increasing or decreasing just by inspection because the bound and both integrand is variable. To make statements there we have to consider it's derivative, which is done by the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

$$ \frac{d}{dx}( \int_0^{\sqrt{x} }e^{ - \frac{u^2}{x} } du) = F(x)= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}  e^{ - \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{x}} } du+ \frac{u^2}{x^2} \int_0^{\sqrt{x} }e^{ - \frac{u^2}{x} } du$$

Now... ummm... we still have the integral again, so it's still not easily possible to make statement if it's increasing or decreasing again.

I thought that I could rule out option D by checking if there is a extrema point on the function by checking roots for $F(x)=0$ but that too seems too difficult.

Is there any trick which I am not seeing? This question was meant for higher schooler's who are entering undergraduate, so methods in that level would be best (other methods are still fine)

Comment: You've done the differentiation incorrectly, I believe.

Comment: How about now @sauslspatz? I think I messed a sign

Comment: Both terms are incorrect.

Comment: Hmm I don't get the error in the derivative inside integral term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done the differentiation correctly, but that's not the best way to do the problem, anyway.

Write $$e^{-u^2/x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\frac{u^2}{x}\right)^n$$

Term-by-term integration gives $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}\frac{u^{2n+1}}{x^n}$$  When we substitute $\sqrt x$ for $u$ in any of the terms, we $\frac{x^{n+1/2}}{x^n}=\sqrt x$ so
$$\int_0^{\sqrt x}e^{-u^2/x}\,\mathrm du=\sqrt x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}$$ and the function is a constant multiple of $\sqrt x$.

**EDIT**

As to the differentiation, the wiki page you linked gives the formula
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{b(x)}f(x,u)\,\mathrm{d}u=f(x,b(x))\cdot\frac{d}{dx}b(x)+\int_0^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,u)\,\mathrm du$$ where I've substituted $0$ for $a(x)$ and $u$ for $t$.  Here we have $f(x,u)=e^{-u^2/x}$, and $b(x)=\sqrt x$, so
$$
f(x,b(x))= e^{-1}\\
\frac{d}{dx}b(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt x}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,u)=\frac{u^2e^{-u^2/x}}{x^2}
$$

Comment: I think I fixed it now, could you have a look if my derivative is correct?

Comment: Very good approach.

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $v=\frac{u^2}{x}$,
$$ \int_0^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{x}}du=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-v}}{\sqrt{v}}dv $$
Now the derivative is easier to calculate, it is $>0$ and diverges to $+\infty$ when $x\rightarrow 0^+$, thus the corresponding graph for the integral is $(C)$.

Comment: [+1] Very short answer !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be called a trick, but I have been guided by the "normal law" in probability :

Setting $\sigma=\sqrt{x}$ and $u=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U$, we get :

$$ I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sigma}e^{-\frac{U^2}{2\sigma^2}}dU$$

By comparison with a well known integral in statistics:

$$K=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_0^{\sigma}e^{-\frac{U^2}{2\sigma^2}}dU\overset{C.O.V. \  U=\sigma x}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_0^{1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx \ \text{ a constant}, 
$$

Remark: $K$ is well known to statisticians, it is the probability that the value of a normal $N(0,\sigma)$ random variable "falls" into interval $[0,\sigma]$ with $K \approx 33 \% .$

which is equivalent to say that:

$$I = \sqrt{\pi}\sigma J=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\pi} J$$

a **square root trend** in $x$: it means the (C) answer.

Comment: That is very strange, the integral is not sensitive to  what value $\sigma$ takes?

Comment: Do not consider the integral only: there is a $\sigma$ in the front fraction as well. See what I have added.

Comment: So that whole fraction is always approximately equal to $K$.. that is interesting

Comment: Not approximately, but equal to constant $K$. In fact a good change of variable makes $\sigma$ disappear and you are left with a $\int_0^1...$ corresponding to a $N(0,1)$ law.

Comment: That is actually very cool.